# Get each 7th record

Tags: postgresql

I have a statistical table in PostgreSQL table:

```
article_id | date       | read_count
    1      | 2011-06-02 | 12
    1      | 2011-06-03 | 54
    1      | 2011-06-04 | 2
    1      | 2011-06-05 | 432
```

And as i need this data in a chart, i need to get values in each week.

I know Postgres has a row_number() function, anyway i didn't get it to work properly.

```
SELECT "date", "read_count" FROM "articles_stats" 
WHERE row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "date" ASC) % 7 = 0
ORDER BY "date" ASC
```

**ERROR:  window functions not allowed in WHERE clause**

Comment: [Windows functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial-window.html) should explain what the error means -- and hopefully insight as to how to can be addressed.

Comment: I actually know what the error means, i'm just asking how to solve the problem. ;-)

Comment: Well, the point is the window function *can't* work in the `WHERE` (of that statement) because neither the result set nor the ordering have been applied yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From @[pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst)'s link,

> "If there is a need to filter or group rows after the window
>   calculations are performed, you can use a sub-select."

For example:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (
          SELECT "date", "read_count", 
                 row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "date" ASC) as n
            FROM "articles_stats" 
         ) x
   WHERE x.n % 7 = 0
ORDER BY x."date" ASC
```

Comment: You can use `row_number() OVER () as n`, which I presume makes the query more efficient because there's less sorting going on.